# What is the Compliance Firehose API in twitter v2?

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy

I am reading the twitter v2 documentation and stumbled upkn the Compliance Firehose API. I did not really get what it does. What are compliance event?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/compliance/batch-compliance/introduction):

> It is crucial that any developer who stores Twitter content offline, ensures the data reflects user intent and the current state of content on Twitter. For example, when someone on Twitter deletes a Tweet or their account, protects their Tweets, or scrubs the geo information from their Tweets, it is critical for both Twitter and our developers to honor that person’s expectations and intent. The batch compliance endpoints provide developers an easy tool to help maintain Twitter data in compliance with the Twitter Developer Agreement and Policy.

The compliance firehose (enterprise, v1.1), and the batch compliance API (v2), enable you to listen for or request information on changes to data you may have stored so that you can update it locally and maintain compliance with the API policy. For example, the *compliance events* include `deleted`, `deactivated`, `scrub_geo`, `protected` and `suspended` for notifying the state of Tweets and accounts.

You would use this API to check for the status of objects in your database and update them to reflect the current state on Twitter, for example, to remove Tweets from your dataset that have been deleted on Twitter, or to not display content from a protected account.